# Pandas Mapping Numbers to another Number

Tags: python, pandas

I have `~5000` rows and all values in my `'Round'` column go from `-1` to `7`. I'm trying to create a new column and it mapped where `-1` = `0` and then anything from `1-7` is `1`. I tried a simple map and listed all the mappings, but this doesn't work.

```
combine['Drafted'] = combine.Round.map({'-1':0,'1':1,'2':1,'3':1,'4':1,'5':1,'6':1,'7':1})
```

Is there something wrong with the logic above that it wouldn't work?

Comment: It could be that your Round column is an integer or a float dtype, instead of a string.

Comment: df.Round.apply(lambda x: 0 if x ==-1 else 1), you can map with the if condition  check also

Comment: Thank you! My round column is a float type, didn't realize it wouldn't work with float. I used the apply(lambda) and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: If `0` doesn't exist as a value (your mapping doesn't include it but you do say from -1 to 7 - so I'm not sure) - you might be able to use `combine.Round.clip(0, 1)`...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can achieve it using below code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Round': [-1, 1, 0, 7, -1, 2, 3, 5, -1, 4, 6]})
df['Drafted'] = np.where(df['Round'] == -1, 0, 1)
print(df)
```

And the output is as below:

```
    Round  Drafted
0      -1        0
1       1        1
2       0        1
3       7        1
4      -1        0
5       2        1
6       3        1
7       5        1
8      -1        0
9       4        1
10      6        1
```